# How to pass information through jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am attempting to pass information from the button within the column "actions" to the modal div, I call the modal using JS, However I am unsure about how to send information from the table over to the div. (Remember it has to be different information for every button as each button is in another row)

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
   $con = new mysqli("localhost","****","****","****");      
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){        
 echo(mysqli_connect_error());       
}
$cuser = $_COOKIE['c_user'];

$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM calls");    
 echo"

<table class=\"table table-bordered responsive\"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th width=\"5%\">#</th> 
                <th>Call Status</th>
                <th>Player ID</th>
                <th>Player Name</th>  
                <th width=\"33%\">Actions</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
 <tbody>";               
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
                                     echo "<tr> ";     
                                       echo("<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> ");
                                       echo("<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td> ");
                                       echo("<td>" . $row['pid'] . "</td> ");
                                       echo "<td>" . $row['pname'] . "</td> ";
                echo "<td> ";
                                    if($row['status'] == 'Pending'){
                                        echo "<a button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-warning\" href=\"calls.php?claim=true&callid=$row[id]\">Claim Call</button /a>  ";
                                    } else if($cuser == $row['claimedby']) {
                                        echo "<a button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" href=\"calls.php?closecall=true&callid=$row[id]\">Close Call</button /a>  ";
                                    } else {
                                                                                            echo "<a button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-warning    disabled\">Claimed</button /a>  ";
                                    }
                                     echo "<a button type=\"button\" href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"jQuery('#modal-2').modal('show');\" class=\"btn btn-info\">Call Info</button /a>  ";
                                     echo "<a button type=\"button\" id = $row[id] href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"jQuery('#modal-1').modal('show');\" class=\"btn btn-success\">Server Info</button /a> ";
                                     echo "<a button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">Join Server</button /a> ";
                                        echo "</td> ";
}   
             echo "</tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>";

echo"<div class=\"modal fade\" id=\"modal-1\">
<div class=\"modal-dialog\" style=\"width: 50%\">
    <div class=\"modal-content\">

        <div class=\"modal-header\">
            <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>
            <h4 class=\"modal-title\">Call Info</h4>
        </div>

        <div class=\"modal-body\" id=\"serverHandle\">

        </div>

        <div class=\"modal-footer\">
            <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>";
  ?>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap's modal?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali I included the modal in the code, its custom.

Comment: @ICostaExDesigns : Do you want to send any kind of information from Buttons to Modal DIV when somebody clicks on those buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send any kind of information from Buttons to Modal DIV when somebody clicks on those buttons ? If that you want then you can add one custom attribute to your button like this `<button info='my-info' id=''>Click</button>` then when someone click on that button you can extract the value from that attribute by using JavaScript `this` & place that to the MODAL window by using any ID from Modal DIV.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to your button along with a click event.

```
     data-value="<?php echo $Something->SomeValue;?>"
```

Then, when the click event gets triggered, you can get the value like this:

```
$(this).data("value");
```

you can use various data-[tag] to pass multiple pieces of information.

Or as an alternative, add this to each button:

```
onclick='someFunction("<?php echo $Something->SomeValue;?>")';
```